# Using web3.py to send a 0 price gas erc20 transaction

Tags: transactions, web3.py, gas-price

Sorry about the formatting, I’m on mobile

I'm trying to push an ERC20 Token transaction with 0 gas price using web3.py. Although when I set the gas price to 0, I receive the following error:

```
{'code': -32000, 'message': 'transaction underpriced'}
```

I know 0 gas price transactions are possible because I’ve seen plenty of them.

Code:

```py
nonce = web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account)

txn = contract.functions.transfer(to_address, amount).buildTransaction(
  {
    'chainId': 1,
    'gas': 1000000,
    'gasPrice': web3.toWei("0", "gwei"),
    'nonce': nonce,
  }
)
signed_txn = web3.eth.account.signTransaction(txn, private_key=account_priv_key)

tx_hash = web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
```

And I need the transaction to be a 0 gas price.
Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: Contract transactions need gas. Calls are free.

Comment: That error message is from the node, it is configured to not accept transactions below certain price.

Comment: @Veilkrand but what about transactions such as this : https://etherscan.io/tx/0x173fd250d63a62bb407f214ff924b49e1c90593572eab1a8c523783f2aa58ba3

Comment: @Ismael can I change the node somehow to a node which accepts 0 price? Or can I set up my own to do that?

Comment: @manilpwn Which ethereum client are you using? Geth has some options to configure it. Search for miner options https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/command-line-options.

Comment: For reference on zero gas transaction in main net: https://medium.com/chainsecurity/zero-gas-price-transactions-what-they-do-who-creates-them-and-why-they-might-impact-scalability-aeb6487b8bb0

Comment: Most likely a transaction with a higher price has already been submitted via the same account and the same nonce.

Comment: @Veilkrand: It is possible to use a price of 0. On a public network it will never execute, but if you run it on a local ganache, for example, then there's no problem with that.